# Rails update or delete on table "products" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, key

I'm developing a app on Rails to sell some products, with a table Users, a table Products and a table Reviews, where the users can write their own reviews on a given product; Now i'm starting to implement the payment system, starting with the monetize gem, but after i added the price field to the Product table and run rails db:seed, causes conflict with the Reviews table... Some advice needed. Present code goes like this:

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo

  has_many :reviews, dependent: :nullify

  monetize :price_cents

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, against: [:name]
end
```

**review.rb**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_11_11_190245) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.bigint "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "price_cents", default: 0, null: false
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "address"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "products"
  add_foreign_key "reviews", "users"
end
```

Sometimes the error goes like this
"PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "product_id" violates not-null constraint"

Thanks for the help

Comment: How does your seed file look like? I guess the problem is there.

Comment: It looks like it is creating something, from the code you shared I would guess a `review`  that `belongs_to` a `product` but it is not giving a `product_id`, which is why you are getting that error.  Find where that is coming from and then make sure a `product_id` value for the related `product` is included.

Comment: If i run rails console, on every review gives me the id of the review, the id of the user and the id of the product thar refers to, so that part is working

Comment: @felipeecst here is an example of my seed file: product = Product.create(
  name: 'Hidratante Corporal em Barra',
  description: 'Óleo de côco bio; Manteiga de karité bio; Óleo de baobab; Cera candelila; OE (benjoim; salva esclareia; vetiver; sândalo amyris; ylang ylang)'
  )
file = URI.open("https://res.cloudinary.com/dmer5xpee/image/upload/v1602070327/ArteQueCura/hidratante_corporal_uengze.jpg")
product.photo.attach(io: file, filename: 'product.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg')